# WebMethod com Modelo de Dados

Tags: c#, entity-framework, web-service, entity-framework-6

Bom dia, gostaria de receber um modelo de dados em um método do meu webservice, qual o procedimento correto para que eu consiga ? Estou tentando o código abaixo porém não está dando certo.

```
namespace UI.Web
{
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]

    public class Services : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        private string ChaveSeguranca = "";

        private BancoContexto contexto;

        public Services()
        {
            contexto = new BancoContexto();
        }

        [WebMethod]
        public string ControleUsuario(Farmacia Farma)
        {
            return "Ok";
        }
    }

}
```

Erro:

> Não é possível serializar o membro
>   Aplicacao.Core.Dominio.Farmacia.Treinamentos do tipo
>   System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[[Aplicacao.Core.Dominio.FarmaciaTreinamento,
>   Aplicacao.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null]] porque ele é uma interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você deve ter algo assim:

```
public class Farmacia 
{
    ...

    public ICollection<FarmaciaTreinamento> Treinamentos { get; set; }
}
```

Mude para:

```
public class Farmacia 
{
    ...

    public List<FarmaciaTreinamento> Treinamentos { get; set; }
}
```